# Magento 2.2.2 : Move Category Navigation Section

Tags: magento2, category

How to move category navigation section after home page banner in magento 2.2
 `class="sections nav-sections"`

and my current site link in magento 2.2 and link and screen short please check

[solivr.mobilegiz.com](http://solivr.mobilegiz.com/)

please check magento 1.9 site link and screen short

[www.solivr.fr](http://www.solivr.fr/)

please advance help for thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not move your banner if you have added your banner in admin cms homepage.

You have to create and call a custom phtml file and then add your banner in that file.

Create following file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homepage.banner" before="navigation.sections" template="Vendor_Module::homepage_banner.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create following file and add your banner here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/homepage_banner.phtml

```
<?php

echo "Add your banner here";
```

Comment: homepage_banner.phtml ma html code muki dau ne

Comment: Yes @RavindrasinhZala

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Create the following file

> **app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="homepage.banner"/>
    </body>
</page>
```